# How to call java methods (which is inside a java package) from PLSQL

Tags: java, plsql

The requirement is to call java methods  from plsql and I am able to achieve it through loadjava command. The steps which I am following is :

Step 1: Create the Java Class/jar file and place it on unix box

Step 2: Load the Java Class/jar into the Database and i can see a new object  in ALL_OBJCETS table  with object type as JAVA CLASS

Step 3: Publish the Function: Creating the function/proc using java static method

Step 4: Execute the Function/proc.

And it's working fine for me but the challenge I am facing here when the java classs is defined  in java package. for example:
the class file is:

==========================

```
package emrsn.com;
public class DBTEST {

    public static String callMe(String input){
        return input;
    }
}
```

========================

Now when I am uploading the above java code (class file) in database  I can see the object name is "emrsn\com\DBTEST", instead of "DBTEST" in ALL_OBJECTS table and the status is INVALID.
I am not able to even recompile the class file in database (using  ALTER JAVA CLASS obj_name RESOLVE), when the object name is like emrsn\DBTEST.

Please let em know if there is any other specific way to refer this type of java class file in database , when it is packaged in Java.
Can you please let me know how do I use these JAVA class objects (when it is emrsn/com/DBTEST) while creating function or while recompiling this object. As mentioned earlier, I can't recompile them to see the exact error.

ALTER JAVA CLASS com/emrsn/DBTEST RESOLVE

Getting below error

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 - "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:
```

And if I am using ALTER JAVA CLASS DBTEST RESOLVE, it's saying object not found. Let me know how I can refer these objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quotes (and forward slashes) and the right keyword depending wether you used class or source files:

```
alter java source "emrsn/com/DBTEST" compile;
-- or 
alter java class "emrsn/com/DBTEST" compile;
-- alternatively use resolve clause
```

To get the full name of all invalid objects use

```
SELECT dbms_java.longname (object_name) FROM user_objects
WHERE object_type = 'JAVA CLASS' AND status = 'INVALID';
```

(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/appendixa.htm)

To use your "callMe"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_call_me(p_input VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR IS LANGUAGE JAVA name 'emrsn.com.DBTEST.callMe(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
sho err
select f_call_me('blah') from dual;
```

Comment: While creating funcion, do I need to use the code as below: 
============================
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DBTEST_FUNC (P_IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'emrsn/com/DBTEST.callMe (java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
    
    If I am doing so , its giving error atr runtime :
    ==============================
    *Cause:    An attempt was made to execute a non-existent method in a   Java class.
    
    Or here also I need to use double quotes.
    
    Appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use java stored procedures without a wrapper function or procedure. Those can be global (like in my example) or package based.

Comment: Yes I do agree. But got stuck for packaged java methods. how do I need to use them in DB functions with slash!!

Comment: Ohh I scrolled your comment and got the solution. Sorry!!